# A particular case of the general converse to the preimage (submanifold) theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

I was thinking whether it would be possible to develop a converse to the preimage theorem in differential topology and I found the following post:

[When is a submanifold of $\mathbf R^n$ given by global equations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78209/when-is-a-submanifold-of-mathbf-rn-given-by-global-equations)

However, I didn't fully understand the main steps described in the post, even for the particular case when $M$ has codimension $1$. Just in case, I'm rephrasing the claim (particular case) and main steps of the proof below:

Claim: Given a connected and compact $n$-manifold $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, there always exists some smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $X=f^{-1}(0)$ and $0$ is a regular value of $f$.

Sketch of the proof in the post: The post suggests that we should take a tubular neighborhood (where can I find a formal definition of the term "tubular neighborhood"?) $U$ of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and identify $U$ with $X \times \mathbb{R}$. This will help us define a function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the required properties. Any idea how to define such $f$ from $U$? Moreover, after the function $f$ is defined on $U$, the post says that $f$ can be extended to the entire space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by a constant function, as $X$ has codimension $1$. How might such extension be constructed? Does this have anything to do with the fact that $X$ is connected and compact?

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestion!

Comment: A tubular neighbourhood $U$ of $X$ is, essentially by definition, a neighbourhood diffeomorphic to $X \times \mathbb R$; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood#Formal_definition) has the formal definition.  The construction of such a neighbourhood is a straightforward application of compactness.  Then $f$ could be, say, $(x, t) \mapsto (\arctan(t))^2$, and you can extend by $(\pi/2)^2$ outside of $U$.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your clarification! However, I'm still confused with a few points: Firstly, why do we have that the tubular neighborhood is diffeomorphic to $X \times \mathbb{R}$? I think the standard Tubular Neighborhood Theorem only gives us that the open neighborhood $U$ of $X$ is diffeomorphic to some open neighborhood of $X$ in the normal bundle $N(X;\mathbb{R}^{k+1})$. Thus, I guess we can only say that $U$ is diffeomorphic to $X \times V$ ($V$ is some open set in $\mathbb{R}$). How does connectedness and compactness of $X$ help us show that here $V$ can be $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Secondly, when you say that "extend by $(\frac{\pi}{2})^2$ outside by $U$", do you just mean that $f(x) \equiv (\frac{\pi}{2})^2 \ (\forall \ x \notin U)$ is set to be a constant function outside of $U$? (One thing I forgot to mention is that we don't require $f$ here to be smooth on the entire space $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$)

Comment: Thirdly, I think another issue in your example is that the derivative of $(\arctan(t))^2$ is zero when $t=0$. Then the differential of the map is not necessarily surjective at $(x,0)$, i.e $0$ is not a regular value. I guess we can easily fix this by replacing $(\arctan(t))^2$ with $\arctan(t)$?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423480/a-particular-case-of-the-general-converse-to-the-preimage-submanifold-theorem#comment1089005_423480), an open and connected subset of $\mathbb R$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423480/a-particular-case-of-the-general-converse-to-the-preimage-submanifold-theorem#comment1089006_423480), yes, that is what I meant.  I don't understand "we don't require $f$ here to be smooth", because your question asks for a "smooth function $f : \mathbb R^{n  + 1} \to \mathbb R$".

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423480/a-particular-case-of-the-general-converse-to-the-preimage-submanifold-theorem#comment1089007_423480), $\arctan(t)$ won't work (we require $\lim_{t \to \pm\infty}$ to be the same so that we can extend by a constant function).  It seems to me that $f^{-1}(0) = \{0\}$ and $\lim_{t \to \pm\infty} f(t)$ equal force $f'(0) = 0$, so I'm not sure what to do there.